# Find a region under a transformation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

I have the following problem. It is from calculus of several variables.

Let $T(u,v)=(u^2-v^2, 2uv)$ and $D^*=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2 \leq 1, \text{with } 0\leq u,v \}.$

Find the region $T(D^*).$

My approach was the following:

I parametrized the quarter unit circle, so...

I take $0\leq t \leq 1$, so $$T(t,0)=(t^2,0)$$ and $$T(-t^2,0)$$ so this gave me an interval $[-1,1]$ in the X-axis.

Then, I take $$T(cos(t),sin(t))=(cos^2(t)-sin^2(t),2sin(t)cos(t))$$ with $0\leq t\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$
and I can't find a way to progress more here.

I realize that an identification with complex numbers may help but I can't see exactly how.

Maybe any idea with$(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $T(z)=z^2$ where $D^{*}=\{z:|z|\leq 1\}.$

Comment: @Suhail -- $D^*$ is smaller than what you wrote.

Comment: Oh, sorry!!  $D^{*}$ is intersection of $|z|\leq 1$ and first quadrant.

Comment: For each $z\in D^{*}$ $|z|\leq 1$ and $0\leq \arg(z)\leq \pi/2$ then $|T(z)|\leq 1$ and $0\leq \arg T(z)\leq \pi.$ Therefore $T(D^{*})=\{z:|z|\leq 1 and \text{Im} (z)\geq 0\}.$

Comment: Now I understand., its half circle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformulating the definition set to
$$
D^* = \left\{\left(u,\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\right) \mid 0 \le u \le r, 0 \le r \le 1 \right\}
$$
then
$$
T(D^*) = \left\{\left(2u^2-r^2, 2u\sqrt{r^2-u^2}\right) \mid 0 \le u \le r, 0 \le r \le 1 \right\}
$$
Using $t=u^2$ we get
$$
T(D^*) = \left\{ \left(2t-r^2, \sqrt{4tr^2-4t^2}\right) \mid 0 \le t \le r^2, 0 \le r \le 1 \right\}
$$
Then $s = 2t-r^2$ and $R=r^2$ turns this into
\begin{align}
T(D^*) &= \left\{ \left(s, \sqrt{2(s+r^2)r^2-(s+r^2)^2}\right) \mid -r^2 \le s \le r^2, 0\le r\le 1\right\} \\
&= \left\{ \left(s, \sqrt{r^4-s^2}\right) \mid -r^2 \le s \le r^2 , 0\le r\le 1\right\} \\
&= \left\{ \left(s, \sqrt{R^2-s^2}\right) \mid -R \le s \le R , 0\le R\le 1\right\}
\end{align}
which is an upper half circle of radius $1$.